# Copy cookies from one WebClient to another?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, parallels

I wonder if it's possible to copy cookies from one web client to another.

### Reason

I am using parallel web requests and it creates new instances of web client on every new thread.

### Problem

Information is sensitive and requires authorization using post request and saves cookie. So basically those new web client instances can't access. I don't want to authorize every single web client that is being created so I wonder if it's possible to somehow just copy the cookies from one web client to another.

### Example Code

```
public class Scrapper
{
    CookieAwareWebClient _web = new CookieAwareWebClient();

    public Scrapper(string username, string password)
    {
        this.Authorize(username, password); // This sends correct post request and then it sets the cookie on _web
    }

    public string DowloadSomeData(int pages)
    {
        string someInformation = string.Empty;

        Parallel.For(0, pages, i =>
        {
            // Cookie is set on "_web", need to copy it to "web"
            var web = new CookieAwareWebClient(); // No authorization cookie here
            html = web.DownloadString("http://example.com/"); // Can't access this page without cookie

            someInformation += this.GetSomeInformation(html)
        });

        return someInformation;
    }
}

// This is cookie aware web client that I use
class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you share the `CookieContainer` between the clients after the authorization?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise Can you show how to do that? Not sure I follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can share `CookieContainer` instances between `WebClient` objects. So once you've authenticated, re-use the same `CookieContainer` for each new client you create.  Just take care that your subsequent requests are not modifying the `CookieContainer`, otherwise you may have a race condition because I doubt the class is thread-safe for parallel modifications.

First, modify `CookieAwareWebClient` with a custom constructor that can have a cookie container passed in.  Also, provide a way to get the container reference via a property:

```
class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer cookie;

    public CookieContainer Cookie { get { return cookie; } }

    public CookieAwareWebClient() {
        cookie = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer givenContainer) {
        cookie = givenContainer;
    }
}
```

Then your `Scrapper` class should pass in its own `CookieContainer` to each client after authentication:

```
public string DowloadSomeData(int pages)
{
    string someInformation = string.Empty;
    CookieContainer cookie = this._web.Cookie;

    Parallel.For(0, pages, i =>
    {
        // pass in the auth'ed cookie
        var web = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookie);
        html = web.DownloadString("http://example.com/");

        someInformation += this.GetSomeInformation(html)
    });

    return someInformation;
}
```